# My dragged objects don't appear on the canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drag

When I run the program and try to drag-and-drop an ellipse on the canvas, the ellipse does not appear on the canvas. Although the mouse cursor shows that I am dragging something and it is possible to drop on the canvas.
Any ideas?

**RESOLVED:** Turns out I was trying to drop on the object it came from instead of the canvas I wanted it to be dropped on (`Ellipse` instead of `Canvas`)!
Thanks for the solution and informative link [Herdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2132796/herdo).

**Code behind:**

```
    private void Ellipse_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse bal = (Ellipse)sender;
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            DataObject sleepbal = new DataObject("sleepbal", bal);
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(bal, sleepbal, DragDropEffects.Copy);               
        }
    }
    private void Ellipse_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse ellipse = (Ellipse)sender; ;
        if (ellipse != null)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("sleepbal"))
            {
                string dataString = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);
                BrushConverter converter = new BrushConverter();
                if (converter.IsValid(dataString))
                {
                    Brush nieuweKleur = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString(dataString);
                    ellipse.Fill = nieuweKleur;
                    Positie = Mouse.GetPosition(AchtergrondCanvas);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(sleepBal, Positie.X);
                    Canvas.SetTop(sleepBal, Positie.Y);
                    AchtergrondCanvas.Children.Add(ellipse);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
    <Canvas Name="AchtergrondCanvas" Height="400" Width="500" AllowDrop="True"></Canvas>

    <Ellipse Name="VoorbeeldBal" Fill="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=BalKleurComboBox}"
                    MouseMove="Ellipse_MouseMove" Drop="Ellipse_Drop"/>
```

Comment: You have to subscribe the event `Drop` of the `AchtergrondCanvas`, not of the `Ellipse`. An very good guide about Drag&Drop can be found on [WPF Tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/draganddrop.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was trying to drop on the object it came from instead of the canvas I wanted it to be dropped on!

Thanks for the solution and informative link [Herdo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2132796/herdo).